# Windows Search for Video Codecs

Tags: search, codec

Is it possible to search a folder for all video files using a certain codec?

I got a bunch of video files from people, and one of the codecs used by some is giving me problems. So I would like to find all files with that codec so I can re-encode those. More specifically I'm looking for all files using msmpeg4. Is this possible in windows (with or without a program I have to download)? There are a lot of files, so it's impractical to check the codecs manually or re-encoding everything.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: Go to the folder with the videos. (If you don't have the File, Edit, etc menu... tap alt) Go to View -> Sort by -> More... I couldn't find "codec" or "encoding" on this list, but I suspect there's a category that may help you. Maybe "video compression?". You'll need to set your view to Details and then sort by that new column.

Comment: That seems to work! I don't get the codec, but some weird string but they seems consistent with the codec. Thanks!

Comment: I found that the video compression column doesn't show any values when in a search result. That's annoying, since most videos are in folders and I tried flattening those folders by searching for "avi", which worked ben then the video compression column is useles.

Comment: The idea behind the new column wasn't to search through that field with a query, it was to sort all the videos by that new column so the group you're looking for are all sorted neighbors.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Though the problem is that the videos are in different folders. So to view all videos in the same "folder" I did a search for "avi", that way I could add the column and sort by it. Though now windows doesn't show content in the "video compression" column when using a search. So now I would have to move all videos to a single folder to get it to work. Problem then is that a lot of videos have the same name.